# Kubernetes: Routing non HTTP Request via Ingress to Container

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

1. I use a local kubernetes bundled with docker on Mac OS.
2. I've installed the [nginx-ingress-controller](https://github.com/jnewland/local-dev-with-docker-for-mac-kubernetes).
3. I managed to send external http [request via ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-controllers) to my kubernetes managed containers (e.g. from my local browser). All request are sent via the nginx ports 80 or 443.

The problem is, that I can only route http or https requests via my ngnix controller.
How can I send non HTTP Requests (e.g. database or corba) via ingress to my containers?

Comment: Can anyone give full manifest files of the service, configMap, and ingress to deploy a simple sftp app in kubernetes using ingress?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is not well supported via the ingress mechanism and is an [open issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23291).
There is a work around for tcp or udp traffic using nginx-ingress which will map an exposed port to a kubernetes service using a configmap.
See [this doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/e8d81034b8f6b3308caac85280e4cf3d93baee1c/docs/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services.md).

Start the ingress controller with the `tcp-services-configmap` (and/or `udp-services-configmap`) argument.

```
args: 
- "/nginx-ingress-controller"
- "--tcp-services-configmap=default/nginx-tcp-configmap"
- "--v=2"
```

deploy configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-tcp-configmap
data:
  9000: "default/example-service:8080"
```

where `9000` is the exposed port and `8080` is the service port

Comment: Is it correct to combine the ingress controller arguments? So I have two configmaps as a result:
--configmap=nginx-ingress/nginx PLUS --tcp-services-configmap=default/nginx-tcp-configmap"

Comment: Unfortunately the solution does not work for me: The exposed port is not accessable. Do I have to tell kubernetes somewhere else to expose that port? Is the configmap really sufficient?

Comment: From the example above, port 9000 is exposed inside nginx-ingress-controller. You can check it out by doing kubectl exec -it <nginx-ingress-controller-pod> bash and doing netstat -nltp | grep 9000. However, I don't see how this port gets accessible from the outside?

Comment: do you know how to do it with helm?

Comment: I tried this solution using `minikube` default nginx load balancer which has the `nginx-ingress-controller:0.21.0`. But it didn't work for me. Is there any restriction to do this in `minikube`?. I tried to upgrade the nginx controller version using `kubectl apply -f`. But the update did not apply to the nginx deployment.

Comment: I am getting this kubelet error: `MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "webhook-cert" : secret "ingress-nginx-admission" not found`

Comment: Just for clarity, to reach the above status, I had to use `runAsuser: 0` as specified in https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2783

Answer (score 5):

I'm using a nginx-ingress-controller on a bare-metal server. In order to get on the hosted sites from all nodes, I created it as a DaemonSet rather than a Deployment ([Bare-metal considerations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#via-the-host-network)).

The solution works well and updates on the Ingress specifications are perfectly integrated.

For the sake of making a TS Server available, I changed my args for the Pods in nginx-ingress-controller.yml as mentioned by stacksonstacks:

```
/nginx-ingress-controller
  --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
  --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx
  --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
  --tcp-services-configmap=default/tcp-ingress-configmap
  --udp-services-configmap=default/udp-ingress-configmap
```

Unfortunately, when applying the changed specification, the DaemonSet did not automatically recreate the Pods, so when inspecting the Pods, I still had the old args:

```
/nginx-ingress-controller
  --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
  --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx
  --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
```

Deleting the Pods inside ingress-nginx namespace with `kubectl --namespace ingress-nginx delete pod --all` made the controller create new Pods and finally the ports were available on the host-network.

I know the circumstances might be a bit different, but hopefully someone can save a few minutes with this.

Answer (score 1):

(One of the comments talked about Helm).
For those who are using [ingress-nginx helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) - most of the configuration is already done.

You just need to go to the relevant protocol section ([tcp](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L887) or [udp](http://udp)) and add the relevant port and service url under it.

For example:

```
tcp: 
  8080: "default/example-tcp-svc:9000"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [Ingress NGINX Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx), you can patch it to enable it to forward requests for your service. This is what I did to get it to work in minikube though the instructions will be very similar for a production-like instance.

```bash
minikube start

# Install the ingress-nginx controller.
minikube addons enable ingress

# Enable the ingress-nginx controller service to also listen on the external port 
# you want. e.g. 9000
kubectl patch service ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx --type json -p '[
    {"op":"add","path":"/spec/ports/-","value":
      {
        "appProtocol": "exampleProtocol",
        "name": "example",
        "port": 9000,
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "targetPort": 9000
      }
    }
  ]'

# Enable an ingress to listen on the external port and forward to your service.
kubectl patch configmap tcp-services -n ingress-nginx -p '
  {
    "data": {
      "9000": "<your-namespace>/<your-service>:8080"
    }
  }'

# Expose the minikube ports locally.
minikube tunnel
```