# How to define some Kubernetes Ingress routes with specific ports

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to create some ingress rules for my Kubernetes cluster (currently, on localhost using Docker Desktop) and they are not working.

#### What I'm trying to do

```
- App #1 : Some database (e.g. mongodb or RavenDb or Postgres, etc).
- App #2 : Some queue (rabbitmq, etc)
- App #3 : Some web site api #1 
- App #4 : Some web site api #2
```

#### Routes to access each app

```
- App #1 : <anything>:port 5200
- App #2 : <anything>:port 5300
- App #3 : /account/*:80, /accounts:80
- App #4 : /order/*:80, /orders/*:80
```

[note -> i'm not including ssl/443 port yet because i've not handled that, etc]

So here's an example what I've got for the first app (which doesn't work):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: data-ravendb-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: data-ravendb-service
          servicePort: dashboard

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: data-ravendb-service
  labels:
    app: hornet
    tier: backend
    component: data-ravendb
spec:
  ports:
  - name: dashboard
    port: 5200
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: data-ravendb-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hornet
        tier: backend
        component: data-ravendb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: data-ravendb-container
        image: ravendb/ravendb
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: dashboard
```

How can I setup my ingress to allow those 4 Apps to access the backend services appropriately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's currently not fully supported to route in Kubernetes Ingress any other traffic than HTTP/HTTPS protocols. Also Traefik which you use is HTTP reverse proxy so it will be either hard or not possible to do that using that ingress controller.

See [Kubernetes: Routing non HTTP Request via Ingress to Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439899/kubernetes-routing-non-http-request-via-ingress-to-container)

Comment: Oh wow really? so the ingress can only accept ports 80 and 443 _regardless_ what ingress-controller is used?

Comment: There are some workarounds for that using nginx controller but they are more like "hacks" than production-ready solutions

Comment: So would this mean I should stop trying to use `ingress` and try instead to use a `loadbalancer` instead?

Answer (score 1):

As @Jakub mentioned, ingress supports only http/https ports.

You can create ingresses with different backend paths for your website apis and also for App1 & App2. But if you need expose with port, then consider using LoadBalancer service.

According your example of first app, why doesn't it works, because you didn't specify `selectors` in your service yaml. Try to change it like below, then it will work.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: data-ravendb-service
  labels:
    app: hornet
    tier: backend
    component: data-ravendb
spec:
  selector: # Mandatory to find backends
    app: hornet # Should match to pod label
    tier: backend # Should match to pod label
  ports:
  - name: dashboard
    port: 5200
    targetPort: 8080
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks heaps for the answer/help. I really want to do _some of my routes_ via PORTS (not hosts or paths) so looks like an LB is the way for me, right now. Time to learn more about that :/